# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

"Стоимость участия в конференции, с учетом партнерской скидки, составит  393 176 рублей".

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, тут уместнее были бы не запятые, а скобки: "Стоимость участия в конференции (с учетом партнерской скидки) составит 393 176 рублей".

Comment: Большое Спасибо!